# Maximum of dependent and independent Gaussians

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Consider a sequence of $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ of i.i.d. normal random variables $\sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$ and another sequence $Y_1, \ldots , Y_n$ of identically distributed random variables $\sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$ that are $\textbf{not}$ independent. Does the following hold with high probability?

\begin{equation}
\max(Y_1, \ldots, Y_n) \leq \max(X_1, \ldots, X_n).
\end{equation}

If not for every $n$, does it hold for large $n$?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: How $X_i$ and $Y_j$ are related?

Comment: they are independent

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the correlations. If the $Y_i$ are approximately independent, this will hold with probability $\frac12$ (by symmetry). If the $Y_i$ are all identical, this will be very likely to hold, with the probability converging to $1$ for $n\to\infty$. Or anything in between.

Answer (score 0):

For $n=2$ the variables can have correlation of $-1$ i.e. one is the opposite of another. In this case the probability in question is $\frac{5}{12}$, because for $\max(X_1,X_2)$ to be greater than $\max(Y_1,Y_2)=|Y_1|$ we need to have at least one of $X_1$ and $X_2$ be positive and greater than $Y_1$ in absolute value. The absolute values of $X_1$, $X_2$ and $Y_1$ can appear in $6$ equally likely orders and considering each one we arrive at this result. We can extend this reasoning and for any even $n$ consider $n$ pairs of variables with correlation $-1$. Thus we want to find the probability:
$$P((X_1,X_2,\dots,X_{2n}) \ge \max(Y_1,Y_2,\dots,Y_{2n}))=P((X_1,X_2,\dots,X_{2n}) \ge \max(|Z_1|,|Z_2|,\dots,|Z_n|))$$
Where $Z_i$ have the same distribution as $Y_i$. This time we have $(3n)!$ equally likely orders and we want to know the probability that at least one $X_i$ woth absolute value greater than all $Z_i$ will be positive. Among all $3n \choose n$ possible locations of $Z_i$ in these $3n$ numbers we have $3n-k \choose n-1$ such that the greatest $Z_i$ is the $k$-th greatest overall. In this case there are $k-1$ greater $X_i$ and the probability that at least one of them is positive is $1-\frac{1}{2^{k-1}}$. Thus the probability in question is:
$${3n \choose n}^{-1} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{3n-k \choose n-1} \left(1-\frac{1}{2^{k-1}} \right)=1-\frac{1}{3}{}_2 F_1(1,-2n;1-3n,\frac{1}{2})\xrightarrow[n \rightarrow \infty]{} \frac{1}{2}$$
Also if $Y_i$ all have equal and lowest possible correlations (i.e. $-\frac{1}{n-1}$) which is equivalent to them summing up to $0$ the result also approaches $\frac{1}{2}$ from below but slower than in the previous setup (from Monte Carlo simulations). It seems that the lowest possible probability tends to $\frac{1}{2}$ as $n$ tends to infinity and the minimum is attained when all variables are conditioned on summing to $0$. However, I don't have any proof nor any proof ideas.